# How can I install a modest but not barest of bare-bones windowing system on top of Fedora-Server?

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde

The title says it, but some detail:

I've got Fedora Server 38 installed (current version). It'd be nice to have a windowing system on the box but it won't be used too often and shouldn't be a full-blown workstation with all that implies in the modern era.

I already tried the bare-bones package and it's TOO bare-bones! To launch an application, like, say `gparted`, you have to go into settings - FAR less than obvious and also far too clumsy... Surely there's something that provides the basics - a copy / paste buffer, terminal window, file-system browser, etc - without going "whole-hog?" Plus, it was a royal pain the bottom to figure out what to install and how to install it, only to find it was, well, again, expecting someone to be a genuine expert in that world.

As an aside, the work-station-like display system naming strategy presently in use in the Fedora community is not helpful in figuring such things out. A what's included or not listing would be FAR more useful, but I haven't found such a thing (yet?!) in the Fedora world. I'd like to not have to become an expert in all these arbitrarily named "desktops" just to know how to choose something that'll work and not be dramatic overkill.

(I appreciated the days when you'd pick sets of packages when doing Red-Hat / Fedora installations, and in those days it was easy to get a good mix of server and workstation.)

Answer (score 1):

Fedora uses the dnf tool to manage installing packages, it has a feature called groups which install bundled collections of packages to provide a capability.

Look at the output of `dnf grouplist`

I suggest you are probably looking for "Xfce Desktop" as probably the lightest gui.

e.g.

```
sudo dnf groupinstall "Xfce Desktop"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think I got my first taste of that grouping when installing the barest of bare-bones windowing systems. ... Does Xfce let me run stuff like, say gparted? I happen to like that app! I guess IDK enough about the boundaries of these window systems; do they all pretty much let any other x11 based app run? Thanks!